# dynamic sql - trying to save value

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic-sql

hey there, basically trying to get the [Field ID] saved into @fieldID so i can use it at another point in the SP. tried various combinations, but i mostly get errors of 'Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ... to data type int.  The [field ID] is an int and primary key. i've even tried casting the [field id] just to make sure, it still fails.

```
Declare @fieldID as int
Declare @sql1 as varchar(1000)
set @sql1 = 'select '+@fieldID+' = [Field ID] from ['+@DataBaseName+'].dbo.[Custom Field Definition] where [Name] = ''Roster Y/N'' and [Table Type] = 0'
  --print @sql1
  exec(@sql1)
```

if i remove the "  '+@fieldID+'   " i get the proper value back.
i know this doesn't work, but is there something like, set @fieldID = exec(@sql1)  ?

thanks for the help!
dave k.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> set @fieldID = exec(@sql1)

you need to use SP_EXECUTESQL with OUTPUT

here is an example

```
DECLARE @chvTableName VARCHAR(100),
@intTableCount INT,
@chvSQL NVARCHAR(100)

SELECT @chvTableName = 'Authors'
SELECT @chvSQL = N'SELECT @intTableCount = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @chvTableName

EXEC sp_executesql @chvSQL, N'@intTableCount INT OUTPUT', @intTableCount OUTPUT

SELECT @intTableCount
GO
```

So, try this

```
DECLARE @DataBaseName VARCHAR(100),
@fieldID INT,
@chvSQL NVARCHAR(300)

SELECT @chvSQL = N'SELECT @fieldID =[Field ID]  from ['+@DataBaseName+'].dbo.[Custom Field Definition] where [Name] = ''Roster Y/N'' and [Table Type] = 0'

EXEC sp_executesql @chvSQL, N'@fieldID INT OUTPUT', @fieldID OUTPUT

SELECT @fieldID
GO
```

Comment: exactly what i needed. was nearly a copy and paste solution. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer is to convert you fieldId to a varchar

```
 Declare @fieldID as int
 Declare @sql1 as varchar(10)
 set @sql1 = 'select '+ Convert(varchar(100),@fieldID)
 exec(@sql1)
```

But as SQLMenace suggests, use SP_ExecuteSQL